# Passar parâmetros URL Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

Preciso passar parâmetros na URL do AJAX para poder filtrar o nome do produto pesquisado. Ou seja, eu tenho um campo tipo `text` e quando a pessoa digita ele já mostra o produto digitado, igual a busca do Facebook.

Como que eu passo estes parâmetros?

Segue o código:

```
$("#buscarProduto").keyup(function (e)
  {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.item-selecionado').fadeOut();

    var buscarProduto = $(this).val();
    var idcategoria = $(".active-button").attr("id");
    var mostraPesquisa = "";

    if(buscarProduto.length == 0)
    {

      $('.item-selecionado').fadeIn();
    }
    else
    {

      $.ajax({
        url: 'http://api.teste/store/produtos?filter[categoria_id]=' + idcategoria  + '?like[nome]=' +  buscarProduto + '',
        method: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(retorno)
        {

          $.each(retorno.data, function(i, item)
          {
            alert(item.nome);
          //  mostraPesquisa += '<li class=\'item-pesquisado\'><span class=\'\'>Nome do Lanche</span></li>';
          })

          $('.item-selecionado').fadeIn();
          $('.item-selecionado').html(mostraPesquisa);
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
          alert("Status do Servidor: " + textStatus);
          alert("Erro do Servidor: " + errorThrown);
        }
      });
    }

  });
```

---

Se eu passar assim:

url: 'http://api.teste/store/produtos?filter[categoria_id]=' + idcategoria,
            method: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
              queryString: "" + buscarProduto + ""
            }

retorna um array vazio. Veja a imagem:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qual é o problema do código atual?

Comment: Ao passar: url: 'http://api.teste/store/produtos?filter[categoria_id]=' + idcategoria  + '?like[nome]=' +  buscarProduto + '', ele não retorna nada

Comment: Mas na API chegam os valores corretos?

Comment: Sim. Somente na hora de fazer a pesquisa. Quando dei aquele alert ali no foreach ele não retorna. Não sei se estou fazendo certo aquele like ali

Comment: Qual o resultado de `console.log(retorno)` dentro da *callback* `success`?

Comment: eu passaria os parâmetros no atributo `data` do ajax ao invés de passa-los via GET na URL, talvez isso tivesse relacionado ao problema.

Comment: Aliás, você utilizou `?like[nome]`, usando `?` para concatenar os parâmetros, enquanto o correto é `&`. Deveria ser `&like[nome]`

Comment: Mesmo assim dá problema, ele não retorna nada. E estou usando o [nome] , pois utilizo para listar os produtos e funcionar perfeitamente.

Answer (score 1):

Já passou tanto tempo, mas eu uso a passagem de parâmetros via campo  data: dentro da tag $.ajax.

Seu exemplo:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'http://api.teste/store/produtos'
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {idcategoria  : idcategoria  , buscarProduto : buscarProduto }
        success: function(retorno)
        {
          ...
         }
```